# Binding to a BindableCollection inside of a custom object WPF + Caliburn.Micro

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, caliburn.micro

I have a class `Item` that has a property of type `BindableCollection` named Children. Each Child has different information that I need to display, here's an example.

```
Public Property CurrentItem() As ObservableCollection(Of ItemModel)
        'Used for displaying all item information
        'Will only hold one item
        Get
            Return _currentItem
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As ObservableCollection(Of ItemModel))
            _currentItem = value
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(Function() CurrentItem)
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(Function() ItemsChildren)
        End Set
End Property

Public Property ItemsChildren() As BindableCollection(Of ChildModel)
            Get
                If CurrentItem.Count > 0 Then
                    Return CurrentItem(0).Children
                Else
                    Return New BindableCollection(Of ChildModel)
                End If
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As BindableCollection(Of ChildModel))
                _itemChildren = value
            End Set
End Property
```

**XAML**

```
 <!-- Child Info DataGrid-->
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsChildren}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="Gray" CanUserAddRows="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Child" Binding="{Binding Path=ChildItem}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=ItemName}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Assy" Binding="{Binding Path=Assembly}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Balloon Number" Binding="{Binding Path=BallNo}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Link Text" Binding="{Binding Path=LinkText}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Qty" Binding="{Binding Path=Quantity}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

*ChildModel is just a class that has properties for the values in the datagrid*

Both CurrentItem's `NotifyOfPropertyChange` do not get run when add items to CurrentItem, so ItemsChildren is not being updated. How can I force `NotifyOfPropertyChange`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work, but in your code CurrentItem is an ObservableCollection(of ItemModel). Because CurrentItem will only ever hold a single value, then it should be:

```
 Public Property CurrentItem() As ItemModel
        'Used for displaying all item information
        'Will only hold one item
        Get
            Return _currentItem
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As ItemModel
            _currentItem = value
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(Function() CurrentItem)
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(Function() ItemsChildren)
        End Set
End Property
```

This should fire the NotifyOfPropertyChange() when the selection from the datagrid changes. In your XAML, you will also need to add a SelectedItem property:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsChildren}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ItemModel, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="Gray" CanUserAddRows="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
```

Hope this helps.